# Edit point size with geom_count (ggplot2, R)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Trying to find a solution to adjust point size when using geom_count. Geom_count enlarges points when points are overlapping. When creating different plots with geom_count, they all show different point sizes (which can be confusing when comparing the plots). I've seen other options in ggplot2 to change point size, but then geom_count is overruled.

Here's an example version of the script:

```
x <- c(10,30,60,80,80,100,30,40)
y <- c(30,70,50,80,80,80,40,50)
db <- merge(x,y)

ggplot(db, aes(x, y))+
  geom_count(alpha=0.8, colour="steelblue")+
  scale_size_area(breaks = round)+
  theme_bw() + theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), plot.tag.position = "bottomleft")+
  labs(title= "X vs Y",subtitle="       ", tag = "A")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to harmonise the point sizes across different plots, you'd need to give it appropriate limits manually. Consider the following example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
#> Warning: package 'patchwork' was built under R version 4.0.3

n <- 10000

df1 <- data.frame(
  x = sample(LETTERS[1:5], n, replace = TRUE),
  y = sample(LETTERS[1:5], n, replace = TRUE)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  x = sample(LETTERS[1:5], n / 10, replace = TRUE),
  y = sample(LETTERS[1:5], n / 10, replace = TRUE)
)

plot1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_count()

plot2 <- ggplot(df2, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_count()
```

The size scales of the two plots are horribly out of sync:

```
plot1 + plot2
```

[image]

You can manually calculate what the limits of the scales should be and apply these to the different plots.

```r
range <- range(c(table(df1$x, df1$y), table(df2$x, df2$y)))

# '&' operation is about the same as adding this scale to individual plots
plot1 + plot2 & scale_size_area(limits = range)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to work! It did gave me odd legend breaks. So for other readers, you can modify the legend by using ```(plot1 + plot2 & scale_size_area(limits = range, breaks=round)``` or you can specify the numbers  ```(plot1 + plot2 & scale_size_area(limits = range, breaks=1:2)```

Comment: This code doesn't seem to work anymore when you have more than two groups. It fails to show some data and you frequently encounter things as 7.5 (which doesn't make any sense). Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example of when it goes wrong?

Comment: In the process of making a reproducible example, I found out where it went wrong! Apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: No apologies needed! Just goes to show that making reprexes are also helpful for self-diagnosis :)